# How to add keybindings to a gtk3 application?

Tags: css, c, gtk3

I'm trying to add keybindings to a gtk3 application via css. This is what I have so far:

```
// add style provider
GtkCssProvider *css = gtk_css_provider_new();                               
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(),         
        GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(css), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);         
gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(css, "bindings.css", NULL);
```

This is the 'bindings.css' that is loaded in the previous code segment:

```
@binding-set tree-view-bindings {
    bind "j" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 1) };
    bind "k" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -1) };
    bind "slash" { "start-interactive-search" () };
}

GtkTreeView {
    color: #F00;
    gtk-key-bindings: tree-view-bindings;
}
```

The color setting works, so it can't be completley broken. But none of the keybindings work. What am I missing?

Comment: There is a dash missing: it's `-gtk-key-bindings` and not `gtk-key-bindings`

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm wrong but I believe you have put the semicolons in the wrong place :)

`@binding-set tree-view-bindings {
    bind "j" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 1); }
    bind "k" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -1); }
    bind "slash" { "start-interactive-search" (); }
}`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me the following:

```
treeview { 
  -gtk-key-bindings: tree-view-bindings;
}
```

So `GtkTreeView` became `treeview` and `gtk-key-bindings` became `-gtk-key-bindings`

Remarks:

- For the proper selector to use you can always use the inspector: Start your app with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive`